# Lowest Common Ancestor dynamic programming approach

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am learning about LCA and came across this [Tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor). I could not understand its O(log n) approach.

First, let's compute a table `P[1,N][1,logN]` where `P[i][j]` is the `2^j`-th ancestor of `i`. For computing this value we may use the following recursion:

[image]

**Preprocessing function**

```
void process3(int N, int T[MAXN], int P[MAXN][LOGMAXN])
  {
      int i, j;

  //we initialize every element in P with -1
      for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
          for (j = 0; 1 << j < N; j++)
              P[i][j] = -1;

  //the first ancestor of every node i is T[i]
      for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
          P[i][0] = T[i];

  //bottom up dynamic programing
      for (j = 1; 1 << j < N; j++)
         for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
             if (P[i][j - 1] != -1)
                 P[i][j] = P[P[i][j - 1]][j - 1];
  }
```

**Query function**

```
int query(int N, int P[MAXN][LOGMAXN], int T[MAXN], 
  int L[MAXN], int p, int q)
  {
      int tmp, log, i;

  //if p is situated on a higher level than q then we swap them
      if (L[p] < L[q])
          tmp = p, p = q, q = tmp;

  //we compute the value of [log(L[p)]
      for (log = 1; 1 << log <= L[p]; log++);
      log--;

  //we find the ancestor of node p situated on the same level
  //with q using the values in P
      for (i = log; i >= 0; i--)
          if (L[p] - (1 << i) >= L[q])
              p = P[p][i];

      if (p == q)
          return p;

  //we compute LCA(p, q) using the values in P
      for (i = log; i >= 0; i--)
          if (P[p][i] != -1 && P[p][i] != P[q][i])
              p = P[p][i], q = P[q][i];

      return T[p];
  }
```

Please help me understand the concept and how the recursion formula `P[P[i][j-1][j-1]` is obtained.

Comment: "Please help to make me understand the concept" is not a very clear question, please be specific about what you don't understand. I can't tell if what you don't understand is about the algorithm or about the implementation. If it's about something in the implementation, your question could be on-topic here, but it looks like a algorithmic computer science question so perhaps it is more suited to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I dont think it is off-topic,  but I think as you first said it is not clear what OP asking for. so this question should be closed.